# How serious is BC42020 in an upgraded VB .Net project?

Tags: vb.net

Consider the following line of code which used to compile without warnings.

```
Public SetUpDone = False
```

After upgrading a project to Visual Studio 2017 from Visual Studio 2005 over a hundred of these BC42020 warnings exist.  The MSDN description of the warning simply states that the variable defaults to type object.  I don't have a good idea of the seriousness of this type of warning.  The debugger indicates that the code executes as I expect.  Is it merely a performance type of issue?

Secondly, I thought that Visual Basic supported some form of Type Inference so I'm not clear about why it wouldn't be able to deduce that the type should be Bool.

Another example is the following where the function returns a String

```
Dim dayTxt = " " & GetTextFromIni("General", "Var50")
```

I would have thought that [type inference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/variables/local-type-inference) would work here and deduce that dayTxt is a String.

Comment: It indicates that the project does not have `Option Strict On`  so that is bad.  Note that your link refers to *local* type inference.  Given the `Public` modifier, `SetUpDone ` cant be a local var.

Comment: First I heard of it.  Very important to mention the VS version you are using, they change fast and 15.8.0 made a lot of victims recently.  Help > About show the number.

Comment: @Hans, the issue in question isn't related to the specific version of VS2017.  It started happening immediately after the upgrade.  At the time it was still 15.4.n.  it has nothing to do with 15.8, but I am slightly curious about what you mean by victims being made by 15.8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
Public SetUpDone = False
```

Is equivalent to this:

```
Public SetUpDone As Object = False
```

As suggested, type inference is only for local variables, not fields.  With `Option Infer On`, this inside a method:

```
Dim SetUpDone = False
```

would indeed be equivalent to this:

```
Dim SetUpDone As Boolean = False
```

There are a couple of issues with the code as you have it.  Firstly, it means that every use of that `False` value requires unboxing which makes your code slower.  That's the case for any value types, i.e. structures.  Value types are normally stored on the stack but, when boxed, are stored on the heap.

Secondly, it means that any member access will require late binding.  That's not an issue for `Boolean` values because they have no members of interest anyway but if it was, say, a `DateTime` then the IDE would never provide Intellisense for that type because al it would see would be type `Object` and the existence of the specified member would have to be confirmed at run time, making the code less efficient again.

Thirdly, it means that the compiler can never confirm that you're passing the correct type as a method argument.  For instance, if you have a method with a `Boolean` parameter, the compiler won't know that you're passing a `Boolean` if you pass that field because it's type `Object`.  That also means that if you pass some other `Object` variable that doesn't contain a `Boolean`, the compiler can't warn you.

As suggested, you should turn `Option Strict On` in the project properties.  That will flag every instance of you're not specifying the appropriate type for something.  Fixing those errors will, at the very least, make your code a bit more efficient.  It may even draw your attention to situations where exceptions will or could be thrown at run time.  Having `Option Strict On` enforces strict typing so it makes you think more about the types you're using.  Even if you're conscientious about that with `Option Strict Off`, you can still make mistakes that `Option Strict On` will prevent.

Comment: The second example I gave was a local variable being set from a function. I didn't know there was an option that had to be set for that to be enabled so I'll try that.

Comment: It turns out that this answer is not 100% correct.  In my experience setting the operation infer to on does eliminate warning BC42020 for class fields in Visual Studio 2017 regardless of what the documentation states.